# How to implement the 'show more' button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to implement button behavior **Show more**.
When I click the button, new objects must be loaded without rebooting.

I do `const [data, setData] = useState(users);` to initialize the first 10 users.
When I press the button, that to this array `data`, I add the following 10 users

```
var users = response.data;
for (var i=0; i < users.length; i++) {
  data.push(users[i]);
}
setData(data);
```

But nothing is rendered in the browser.

how to do it correct?

```
const Cards = ({users, bottomUrl }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(users);

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const page = bottomUrl.slice(-1);
    const axios = require('axios');
    const url = '/users';

    axios.get(url, {
      params: { page: page }
    }, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
    .then(function (response) {
      var users = response.data;
      for (var i=0; i < users.length; i++) {
        data.push(users[i]);
      }
      setData(data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
    .then(function () {
      // always executed
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="users-list">
        {data.map((element, elIndex) => (
          <UserCard
            key={elIndex}
            lastName={element.lastName}
            firstName={element.firstName}
            description={element.description}
          />
        ))}
      </div>

      <div className="users-page-button-container">
        <a className="button" onClick={handleSubmit} href={bottomUrl}>Show more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  )

};
```

Comment: when you click on `show more`, does it fetch 10 records only?

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing on the state object `data`. You must use an intermediate variable and pass that to `setData`

Answer (score 0):

You are manipulating the state directly, which is wrong. Please update the handleSubmit method as below.

```
 const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const page = bottomUrl.slice(-1);
    const axios = require('axios');
    const url = '/users';

    axios.get(url, {
      params: { page: page }
    }, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
    .then(function (response) {
      users = response.data;
      setData([...data, ...users]); // You need to save the previous data along with the new data and pass it together to setData function. So here data = previous data + new users data
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
    .then(function () {
      // always executed
    });
  };
```